# MP Android Chart - Bar chart with time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I am trying to draw a bar chart with the timing with the use of MpAndroidChart library.

```
    val time = ArrayList<String>()
    time.add("12 AM")
    time.add("4 AM")
    time.add("8 AM")
    time.add("12 PM")
    time.add("4 PM")
    time.add("8 PM")
   
    binding.barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(time)
    binding.barChart.xAxis.setLabelCount(time.size, true)
```

But in xAxis I am only getting the 2 labels **12 AM** and **4 PM**

How can I get all the labels to be displayed?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Could you please share a code snippet of your IndexAxisValueFormatter, please?

Comment: IndexAxisValueFormatter is a function defined in MPAndroid Chart library

Comment: You can add a custom xAxis Formatter as well - that's why I asked. Also, have you tried removing this ``` binding.barChart.xAxis.setLabelCount(time.size, true)``` to see how many labels do you get?

Comment: Yes Lilya, I have tried that as well but same result.